Encountering Strange Issues When Installing CUDA 12.3 and Visual Studio 2019 on Windows！

VS Version: VS2019 Version 16.11.8

CUDA Version: cuda_12.3.0_545.84_windows

Windows system: Windows Server 2019 Standard


Install Steps:
First, I installed VS2019.
Then, I installed CUDA 12.3, selecting the option to integrate with Visual Studio during the setup.
I created a CUDA C++ console application in Visual Studio.
Finally, I compiled a demo program and received the following error:

nvcc fatal: nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft visual studio. only the versions between 2017 and 2019(inclusive) are supported!

However, after checking, I found that my CUDA version corresponds to the version of Visual Studio. I am unsure what might be causing the issue. Could anyone please help me analyze it?
CUDA 12.3 Installation Guide for Microsoft Windows:

Windows Compiler Support in CUDA 12.3:



Compiler*
IDE




MSVC Version 193x
Visual Studio 2022 17.0


MSVC Version 192x
Visual Studio 2019 16.x


MSVC Version 191x
Visual Studio 2017 15.x (RTW and all updates)




I noticed that the compilation error suggested adding the nvcc flag -allow-unsupported-compiler to bypass the compiler version check. However, after adding this flag, I encountered the following error, and I have not yet found a solution.

CUDACOMPILE: Command-line: invalid Microsoft version number: 0


when installing visual studio, you must select the option to install MS VC++ toolchain. This requirement is indicated in the table (from table 1 in the document you linked).

@RobertCrovella Yes, I have already installed it, and I wrote a simple c++ program as an example: std::cout<< _MSC_VER<<std::endl; the output: 1929
